# Ad-Hoc Builds for Static Libraries (Testflight)

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit, testflight

i have spent a few hours on this to no avail. I have an application that has the static library Restkit. I hit upon quite a few errors, so i did the following:

1. added ad-hoc to restkit proj
2. added entitlements.plist to the restkit proj, with one key (can be debugged = NO)
3. after failing many times, as a last resort, i also added a info.list, with one key (get-task-allow=YES)

From here, the archiving works. But when i try to upload to testflight, it says that the:

"'Invalid Profile: developer build entitlements must have get-task-allow set to true"

I am very much stuck.

I also notice that some people have mentioned setting **skip-install = NO** but you end up with a archive with multiple applications when you do that, which cannot be signed or validated.

- i have also asked this on TF forum. will cross answer here if i get a reply, but very much hoping for help here too.

Comment: This page on the TestFlight website may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523191/invalid-ipa-error-on-testflight-the-aps-environment-in-your-embedded-mobileprov

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RestKit has an extremely active mailing list [here](http://groups.google.com/group/restkit?pli=1) where the authors of the framework are very responsive. It may be worth throwing this question up there as well.

However, the message you're seeing above is suggesting that you're building using your development profile rather than your distribution profile. When you build using your development profile it expects

```
get-task-allow
```

to be set to true so that you can debug the app whilst it's running on the device.

TestFlight has a pretty comprehensive tutorial [here](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4) on how to properly setup an archive for ad hoc distribution.

Comment: you are right! But now i am getting another error. This is really killing me: The APS environment in your embedded.mobileprovision and your binary don't match

Comment: @ming-yeow This suggests your Push Notification settings don't match your profile. Have you set-up Push Notifications for both Development and Production?

Comment: i did. I managed to solve it, but without jumping thru lots of hoops and taking a good nap in between! and thanks a lot for your help - it pointed me to the right direction. much appreciated =)

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523191/invalid-ipa-error-on-testflight-the-aps-environment-in-your-embedded-mobileprovi