# Invalid IPA error on Testflight: The APS environment in your embedded.mobileprovision and your binary don't match

Tags: objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications, ad-hoc-distribution

I am sorry for posting so many questions, but getting this to work has been incredibly painful, even tho Testflight makes it much easier

```
Invalid IPA error: The APS environment in your embedded.mobileprovision and your binary don't match
```

I figure this has got to do with my Apple Push Notifications. I am using my distribution profile across all my settings. My app has been configured to both development and production.

What could the causes of this error be?

As a side note, I have been working on this for the entire day, and I get stuck at one thing after the other, esp involving static libraries and xcode4. Am I really bad at this, or does Apple really make it so hard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it was an xcode bug. Here's how i solved it, and maybe it can be useful for some users in the future. Including my problem solving steps for reference:

1. i changed the entitlement file to aps-environment = production. No go, still different between the 2 files.
2. i changed ALL my settings (debug/not) to the distribution profile, just to be sure
3. I built it again, and checked out the embedded.mob and binary as you suggested
4. No go again.
5. I went nuclear - deleted all my profiles, downloaded only the distribution build i needed
6. here is when it became interesting - i could not build it on debug (expected), but i was having the same problem of "profile not found" even when i was in ad hoc archiving mode. Surely that means that there remains a reference to the developer mode even when i was trying to archive it (given that i have already changed ALL my settings and deleted all my other profiles)
7. So i digged up project.pbxproj, and found the offending line that was still trying to access my development profile in ad hoc build. I changed it manually, and bingo, things worked as per expected

End of the day, i am surprised why this would happen. It seems like an xcode 4 bug. Normally it is my fault when these things happen, but this seems arcane enough (plus i had so much trouble with xcode 4 for a few other things).

Solved with help from the amazing Testflight team!

http://support.testflightapp.com/discussions/tools/17-invalid-ipa-the-aps-environment-in-your-embeddedmobileprovision-and-your-binary-dont-match

Comment: Thanks! Which line in the pbxproj was accessing your non-distribution profile? I'm still stuck with getting push working with testflight

Comment: I had problems with this as well. Didn't nuke everything, but changed all of my code signing entities to use the iphone distribution profile  (which was tied to my ad hoc provisioning profile). Restarted xcode (4.2), and it worked! Changed the prod code signing back to 'don't code sign', and it still works. Not sure what it is, seems like most probably a xcode bug

Answer (score 2):

Also, particularly if the target you're archiving was based on another target, double check that your target's "Archive" Scheme is based on the correct Build Configuration of Build Settings.

- In Xcode 4.2 next to the run menu, click on  -> Edit
  Scheme
- Click on the 'Archive' button in the left drawer
- Look at 'Build Configuration

For Testflight, I replicate my Release Build Configuration, and rename it 'Ad Hoc' for just this purpose, specifying my Ad Hoc provisioning profile and whatever else needs to be in there. If you've gotten this far, I presume you've already done that, but for posterity, I figured I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this error before as well, so follow these instructions for this to work:

1. Create a provisioning profile for your app and add the devices to it of the people who should test it.
2. Build your application using that provisioning profile you just created and export it as an *ipa.
3. Upload it to TestFlight and select the devices that you want to test the app on.

Many people miss step 2, (so did I) and that's essential for it to work. So give it a try! :)

Comment: Hi david, thanks a lot! I was able to solve it a different way, but your help is much appreciated. these things are... arcane.

Answer (score 0):

Replying this question, in case someone bumps onto this while uploading an air mobile app.

Make SURE you check the Entitlements element in your app.xml.

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <!-- iPhone and iPod touch devices -->
            <string>1</string>
            <!-- iPad devices -->
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
        ]]>
    </InfoAdditions>

    <!-- This part below.. -->
    <Entitlements>
        <![CDATA[
        ]]>
    </Entitlements>
```

My Entitlements looked like this back when I got the error:

```
    <Entitlements>
        <![CDATA[
            <key>application-identifier</key>
                <string>QFY9MVY9K8.com.somethingHere.anAppName</string>
            <key>aps-environment</key>
                <string>development</string>
        ]]>
    </Entitlements>
```

This is how it looks now:

```
    <Entitlements>
        <![CDATA[
            <key>get-task-allow</key>
            <false/>
        ]]>
    </Entitlements>
```

This error was caused because

1. I used a DIFFERENT ID in the `<key>application-identifier</key>` than the one in my provisioning profile.
2. I used `development` key instead of `production` in the `<key>aps-environment</key>` part.